# Default value not overridden upon form submission

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, geolocation, hidden-field

I've got a hidden field inside a form, which I create using Drupal's form API like this:

```
$form['position'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden',
  '#default_value' => '57.149953,-2.104053',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'id' => 'geoposition',
  )
);
```

When I load the page in which the form is rendered, I have a little bit of JavaScript that edits the hidden field like so:

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition, noPosition, 10);
}

function getPosition(position) {
  var pos = document.getElementsByName("position");
  pos.value = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
  alert(pos.value);
}
```

Now, the last statement in this snippet actually outputs the correct value of the user's current position. However, when I submit the form, the value passed onto the server for manipulation is the default value, and not the updated value. The value to use after the form has been submitted is picked up like this:

```
$map_field .= 'src="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q='.$form_state['values']['position'].'&amp;output=embed"></iframe>';
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Could it be a security issue where I'm trying to change the url of the $map_field and updating it via JS is a concern? Because I'm updating it via JS, then sending it to PHP and putting the value in an <iframe>

http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/a/frame3.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved it by using the getElementById() method instead of getElementsByName() method. For some reason the name wasn't working. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wud do:

1) Disable to js for now.
2) Use xdebug to see the value before and after the form has been submitted. This should help to see  if something is going wrong.

Cheers,
vishal

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using #default_value, consider using #value - because that is the value that gets posted.

Comment: That's not the issue. The Drupal standard is to use #default_value if the input field is hidden and you are going to change it with JS. Thanks for your answer though!